# Text moving during the transition animation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

guys, I have a problem with animations. I have an image that does some transition on hover but the text just underneath is slightly moving. I need it to stay in place as its messing with my layout. I have tried to use absolute position as suggested in a similar problem here but didn't work for me. Do you have any ideas how I could fix it?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdWLgw

```html
<div class="album-item">
  <div class="album-img"><img src="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music114/v4/97/e6/70/97e670f6-361b-a23d-617a-52bafcd631cd/075679854247.jpg/170x170bb-85.png" /></div>

  <div class="album-card">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <span>name</span> <span>released</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.album-item {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 25px;
}

h4 {
  align-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.album-img {
}

img {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.12, 1.12);
  transform: scale(1.12, 1.12);
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.album-card {
}
```

You can see it barely moves here but I have multiple tiles like this and it really messes up so I need the text to stay in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to stay put, don't change the geometry of the elements above it between the two states. In your case, you're changing the size, by giving the border of the element above different widths.

To fix it, give the non-hovered element an equal border width with color transparent.

```css
.album-item {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 25px;
}

h4 {
  align-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.album-img {
}

img {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: block;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.12, 1.12);
  transform: scale(1.12, 1.12);
  opacity: 1;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.album-card {
}
```

```html
<div class="album-item">
  <div class="album-img"><img src="https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music114/v4/97/e6/70/97e670f6-361b-a23d-617a-52bafcd631cd/075679854247.jpg/170x170bb-85.png" /></div>

  <div class="album-card">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <span>name</span> <span>released</span>
  </div>
</div>
```